# How to set user's privileges from LDAP via OpenDS

Tags: ldap

I have setup a simple LDAP server using OpenDS. I would like to set the user privileges and I have no idea how to do it. Am I supposed to achieved this by modifying the ACL? If yes, how do I go about doing it? Or is there any options in OpenDS that allows me to set the privileges??

Anyone advice or guide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenDS has a pretty extensive documentation available on the wiki of OpenDS.org
and how to set privileges to a user is here : https://www.opends.org/wiki/page/AssigningPrivilegesToNormalUsers

Privileges allow user to do specific administrative tasks. To control access to the data, use the ACL.